# Remote to support users over the internet

Tags: windows, remote-access

I am new to VNC/remote assistance. I would like to check if there is any free/suggested software that allow remote assistance/ full control to clients' computer.

Requirements are as the following:

1. free/low cost
2. remote to client PC without the need of client UI interaction (direct remote, bypassing users' authorization)
3. no need to configure anything manually such as a port number.
4. Windows platform
5. over the internet

Answer (score 2):

"**TightVNC** is a free remote desktop application. With TightVNC, you can see the desktop of a remote machine and control it with your local mouse and keyboard, just like you would do it sitting in the front of that computer."

Runs on Windows Windows XP / Vista / 7 / 8 / 8.1 / 10 (and 11)

Homepage: https://www.tightvnc.com/

Download: https://www.tightvnc.com/download.php